# VS Code reverting js-beautify code formatting on save

Tags: javascript, formatting, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I've installed the `js-beautify` for VS Code extension.

I wrote a `.jsbeautifyrc` file with my preferred formatting which is located in the root of my project.

I bound a short cut `(ctrl-alt-l)` to format the document (which works perfectly).

As per their documentation I set "`editor.formatOnSave`" to `true`, which should format code on save (this is not working).

Currently, every time I save the document all my code formatting is reverted back to the default VS Code formatting.

I also tried setting "`editor.formatOnSave`": to false which had no effect. All formatting in the document gets reverted back.

What I expected was the `.jsbeautifyrc` file to be respected when saving the document.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Would love to hear a solution. I thought that adding the `beautify.config` path might get it to register, but that didn't do it either. 

The best case scenario would be js-beautify trumps the vscode format for js, css, html files under the same key binding.

Comment: @AlexSashaRegan Unfortunately I never found a solution for this issue. If by chance you figure this out could you please let me know?

Comment: I submitted an issue on the github repo. You can follow it at [formatOnSave not using .jsbeautifyrc #133](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/issues/133)

Maybe post your settings for the same problem on that issue link. You'll get notifications that way at least.

Comment: I thought he said you shouldn't download it yet. He's still working ont

Comment: This appears to have been resolved in the GitHub issue.